# C: How do I allocate an exact amount of bytes to a string?

Tags: c, string

Here's my function.

```
char * substring(int begin, int end, char * string)
{
int size = end - begin + 1;
char * s = (char *)malloc (sizeof(size));

int i; 

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    s[i] = string[begin++];
}

return s;
}
```

So let's say my string was only supposed to be "I". But when I try to print out the string later, I get I + 3 extra characters that were unintended. How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you determining `begin` and `end`?

Comment: Is `s` null terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra characters printed since you haven't null-terminated the `s` string:

```
s[i] = 0;
return s;
```

Fix the allocation to size, and also note that the following may depend on your interpretation of `begin` and `end`, but if you interpret the `end` as pointing to the last character you intend to copy (this would be a-typical), then you will need to adjust the `size` by 1.

Comment: Also, remember to allocate one more byte for the null character.

Comment: @Mike I didn't see that `int i` was outside the loop. nevermind.

Answer (score 6):

First, change the line

```
char * s = (char *)malloc (sizeof(size));
```

to

```
char * s = malloc( size + 1 ); // + 1 for null terminator
```

`sizeof (size)` gives you the number of bytes in an integer (2 to 4 to 8 depending on your platform), which is not necessarily what you want.

Next, use the `strncpy` function to copy the first `size` characters of `string`:

```
strncpy( s, string, size );
```

Make sure the string is null-terminated:

```
s[size] = '\0';
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, leave a comment as to *why* so I can fix the problem.

Comment: Very clean, nice explanation, good use of existing functions. Just that I *hate* spaces after '(' and before ')'... Oh well, can't have eveything ;-)

Comment: Any particular reason for favoring `strncpy( s, string, size )` vs. `memcpy( s, string, size )`?

Comment: @vonbrand: It's a style I've only recently adopted; my eyesight is rapidly deteriorating, and it makes the code easier for me to read.  I'm not sure why `s[size] = '\0';` is any better than `s[size] = 0;`, though.  I prefer to think of the terminator as an out-of-band value, so it makes sense to me to just use a naked `0`.  Again, my eyesight is encouraging me to declutter where possible.

Comment: For the sake of correctness, the terminator is called NUL ;)

Comment: @user3125367 The C spec call `'\0'` the "null character" and does not call it "NUL".  ASCII calls `'\0'` the "Null character" and abbreviates as "NUL".

Comment: @JohnBode This is a bit late, but no one downvoted your post. They "unupvoted" for a second.

Comment: @remyabel: there was a downvote active for a while; it has since been removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior waiting to happen. Your biggest problem is that your allocation should be

```
char * s = (char *)malloc (size);
```